# Does ServletContextListener invokes the method called each time machine reboots

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, servletcontextlistener

Actually i have the requirement to execute a method which takes hours to complete on every machine reboot.I have deployed my web application on apache tomcat and i have enabled automatic start of Apache tomcat.For this I have called a method in ServletContextListener contextInitialized in a simple java class.Now my doubt is does the method called in contextInitialized  will be executed each time the machine reboots.

Here is my ServletContextListener  implemented class..

```
public class Startup implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
}

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    // Do your startup work here
    System.out.println("Started....");
    //captureCDRProcess();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            captureCDRProcess();
        }
    }).start();

}
```

and this is my web.xml..

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.myapp.Startup</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Please guys help me ..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can't you find this out for yourself by rebooting and seeing whether anything gets logged? (Yes, I'd expect that it would happen...)

Comment: Exactly. *Why* do you have any doubt about it? What part of the specification didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have deployed my web application on apache tomcat and i have enabled automatic start of Apache tomcat.

Yes , for each start of Tomcat , `ServletContextListener`'s `contextInitialized` method invokes.

Answer (score 1):

the method will be executed each time the tomcat starts.

If you don't want this, you can create a .jar library with a method main that you can invoke this from a cron that you can program when you want to execute.